# Using linq spliting the text file and storing into the datatable

Tags: asp.net

My requirement is I need to split a text file and store into a datatable. Refer 
the following code and column separator "|" and row separator "^":

```
var text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
var lines = text.Split('^');
var rows = lines.Select(l => new {Line = l, Fields = l.Split('|')});
var colCount = rows.Max(r => r.Fields.Length);

var tblRegistration = new DataTable();
for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++)
{
    tblRegistration.Columns.Add("Column" + i, typeof (string));
}
```

When it is correct format it will work fine.

But end user may upload text file like

```
adfafdsafsdfsdfs^fsdf|sfsdf|sdfsfd|dfs...
```

in the first row there is only one column, but there should be four.
In this case how to validate it?

Comment: What is the desired result, should it be in the first column and 2-4 are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your desired result is that you fill every column from left to the right it's easy:

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var newRow = tblRegistration.Rows.Add();
    newRow.ItemArray = row.Fields;
}
```

So your example file would generate this `DataTable`:

```
Column1            Column2   Column3    Column4
adfafdsafsdfsdfs            
fsdf               sfsdf     sdfsfd     dfs
```

If you want to throw an exception:

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    if(row.Fields.Length != tblRegistration.Columns.Count)
        throw new Exception("Please upload the correct format");

    var newRow = tblRegistration.Rows.Add();
    newRow.ItemArray = row.Fields;
}
```

Comment: no in that case i should throw exception saying that upload correct format

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you should probably have something like:

```
// Call ToList to avoid splitting every time you access
var rows = lines.Select(l => new {Line = l, Fields = l.Split('|')}).ToList();

var expectedColumns = rows[0].Fields.Length;
if (rows.Any(row => row.Fields.Length != expectedColumns))
{
    // There's a broken row. Throw an exception or whatever...
}
```

That's assuming that *all* rows should have the same number of fields, of course.

If you want to show the broken row, you could change it to:

```
var firstBadRow = rows.FirstOrDefault(row => row.Fields.Length != expectedColumns));
if (firstBadRow != null)
{
    // Handle it however you want...
}
```

Comment: No no ..in that case i should display user msg file does not match with imported format

Comment: @user1384356: Right, so it sounds like *in this method* you should quite possibly throw an exception, but it should be *handled* elsewhere. I wouldn't expect you to be mixing the "how to display a result to the user" code with the parsing code itself.

Comment: exactly i need to show exception..but am not getting how to show

Comment: @user1384356: That's a completely different problem - I suggest you ask a separate question. It's important to break a task up into smaller tasks - you have two problems 1) detecting problems; 2) displaying errors.